# Pyspark: Is it required to pass additional modules as --py-files argument in a project

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, project-structure, modular

I am creating a pyspark application which is modular in nature. My code struture is like:

```
├── main.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── logic.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── utility.py
```

My start script is `main.py` which in turn call logic function in the `logic.py` file.

I am running my project like `spark-submit main.py`

My question is do i need to mention other `.py` files in the spark-submit command or they automaticlly get imported.

I come accross a post which mention to zip the src folder and pass it as argument in --py-files.

Which is the right way?

Should i keep the current structure and run code from main.py like i do.?

Is there any difference in these two ways? (logical and performance wise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running locally there is no need to pass additional modules as zip with the `--py-files` flag, your code is local and so is the master and workers (they all have access to your code and modules necessary).

However, when you want to submit a job to a cluster, the master and the workers need to have access to your `main.py` file, along with all the modules it uses, thus, using the `--py-files` argument, you are specifying the location of the extra modules and both master and workers have access to every part of the code that needs to be run. If you just run `spark-submit main.py` on a cluster, it won't work because 1) the location of main.py is relative to your system, so the cluster won't be able to locate main.py and 2) due to ImportErrors of the main.py.

Note: The usage of this flag is before specifying the `main.py` and the zipped files (as well as `main.py`) need to be somewhere accessible to the whole cluster, not local on your machine, e.g. on an ftp server.
For example, to submit on a cluster through mesos:

```
spark-submit --master mesos://path/to/service/spark --deploy-mode cluster --py-files http://somedomainforfileserving/src.zip  http://somedomainforfileserving/main.py
```

**Edit**: As for `jar` dependencies, e.g. the ElasticSearch connector, you can put the jars within the `src`, e.g. in `src/jars`, so that it gets zipped and distributed to all, and then when submitting to your cluster, reference the relative to `src` path to the jar. E.g.:

```
spark-submit --master mesos://path/to/service/spark --deploy-mode cluster --jars src/jars/elasticsearch-spark-someversion.jar --py-files http://somedomainforfileserving/src.zip  http://somedomainforfileserving/main.py
```

Comment: Do i zip the **whole** project or just the `src` part? and can i submit multiple zip files like instead of the `src` i have two modules `jobs` and `utils` outside the src folder.

Comment: @JugrajSingh It will work both ways, but zipping just the `src` seems the most logical thing to do (`main.py` within the `zip` will be ignored either way,).

Comment: Is there any good resources for production grade pyspark project that can answer all related questions?.

Comment: Is there a particular Structure to pyspark project like where to specify jar dependencies and configuration files etc. or its all ones own confort.

Comment: @JugrajSingh I haven't found any good resources for production grade spark deployment so far unfortunately, learning all this stuff in the usual, painful way, `research ... try ... catch ... repeat`. DataBricks and the Apache Spark documentation has the best resources I've seen up to now - along with SO. I will post if I find anything of great use. Good luck!

Comment: @JugrajSingh Added edit for the `jars` dependencies. In general, make sure the master and the workers have access to whatever your code needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, zipping your project then submitting will work. 
Move to your project folder. Run `zip -r myproject.zip .` .
Now you can `spark-submit --py-files myproject.zip main.py` in a terminal.